# Javascript sorting input values into an array

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which looks at hidden inputs with the class howmanyproducts.

```
$("#proddiv .howmanyproducts").each(function() {
    var idval = $(this.id).val();
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is for each id get the value and sort the ids into an array based on their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add both your ids and the corresponding values to an array, then to use the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of your array with an adapted *compare function*. Let say your values are number but are retrieved as string :

```
    // Create a new empty array :
    var ids = [];
    $("#proddiv .howmanyproducts").each(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var val = $(this.id).val();
        // Store the id and the value:
        ids.push([id, +val]);
    });
    // Sort the array in place, using the second element of each item
    // ie. the value :
    ids.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
    // Once sorted, make a new array with only the ids:
    var result = ids.map(function(a,b) { return a[0] });
```

I used the traditional syntax, but note that it can be written more simply using arrow functions:

```
ids.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
var result = ids.map((a,b) => a[0]);
```

Comment: I need to display the ids in the array rather than their values but the sort needs to be on the values. does it need to be multi-dimensional?

Comment: Yes you can use it on a multi-dimensional array, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfValues = [];

$("#proddiv .howmanyproducts").each(function() {
    arrayOfValues.push($(this).val());
}
```